# Absolute values when normalising the wavefunction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, complex-numbers

My question concerns Problem 1.4 from Griffiths. I understand the general working of the problem (given below), and derived the correct result for the normalisation constant $A$, but I am troubled by the modulus signs around $A$ and then its disappearance later in the workings.

During the process of normalisation, one must calculate the integral of the square of the modulus of $\Psi$ - fine - but then during the provided workings of the answer, only $A$ is rendered as $|A|$, other factors in the definition of $\Psi$ are left as is. Furthermore at the end of the workings the modulus sign around $|A|$ appears to magically disappear.

The problem is thus: Normalise by calculation of $A$ the wavefunction

$\Psi(x,0)= \begin{cases} A(\frac{x}{a}), &\qquad \text{for } 0 \leq x \leq a \\ A(b-x)/(b-a) &\qquad \text{for }  a \leq x \leq n \\ 0 &\qquad \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$

And the provided workings (which I have slightly paraphrased) are:

$$
\begin{align}
\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} | \Psi(x,t) |^2 dx &= 1 \\
&= \int^a_0 | A \frac{x}{a} |^2 dx + \int^b_a  A \frac{b-x}{b-a}|^2 dx \\
&= \frac{|A|^2}{a^2} \int^a_0 x^2 dx + \frac{|A|^2}{(b-a)^2} \int^b_a (b - x)^2 dx \\
&= \frac{| A |^2}{a^2} \frac{x^3}{3} \bigg\rvert^a_0 + \frac{|A|^2}{(b-a)^2} \int^b_a -\frac{(b-x)^3}{3} \bigg\rvert^b_a \\
&= \frac{|A|^2 b}{3} \\
&\therefore A = \sqrt{\frac{3}{b}}
\end{align}
$$

I am aware of a similar question to this one concerning absolute values when normalising, however the answers to that question were all specific to that user's particular problem, from which I am unable to abstract a general rule, and furthermore that question does not ask about the condition for the conversion of $|A|$ back to $A$ at the end of a problem such as this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Steven Sagona's answer is completely right, I'll just complement with different wording:
At the end of your calculation, you're left with the equation:
$$ |A|^2 \dfrac{b}{3} = 1 $$
You still need an additional assumption on the space in which A lives. The more general one would be $A \in \mathbb{C}$. in which case you have an infinite amount of answers: $A=e^{i\theta}\dfrac{3}{b} \ \ \forall \theta \in \mathbb{R}$.
You could avoid this degenerancy by saying $A \in \mathbb{R}$, and that leaves you with two possible answers: $A = \pm \dfrac{3}{b}$.
For most cases in physics, when no additional information is provided, it is pretty much standard to take the easiest and simplest of possible answers, which in this case would be to take the positive one, since you avoid an extra sign in your wavefunction that would serve no particular purpose.

It is particularly important to have in mind the phrase "when no additional information is provided", as pointed out by Steven's answer, you could have some other measurement giving information about the phase, which would provide a second equation to solve exactly the equation for complex A.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of normalization is to correct for the probabilities adding up to 1 correctly. The true value of $A$, as you've said can have a complex factor. So there's an infinite set of different values of $A$ with different values $e^{i \theta}$ that all normalize the state of interest.

How do you know which is the right one? You can't know in this example. The only way to figure out the phase is by doing a measurement that see's that phase (by causing the wave to add up or subtract, thereby changing result by the value of $e^{i \theta}$ ).

That is why in this context they are interchanging $A$ and $|A|$.